# External folder inside the repo

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have an images directory located outside my theme folder. And I have pushed my theme directory to github. The location of the image directory is rational at this point, since I want the site to be able to get images even when the theme is changed.

I don't want my colleagues to keep track of multiple repos. What I want is a folder(more like a link to the image folder) inside my current repo, so when someone clones my repo he gets the image directory too, where he can make all the changes he wants but nothing in regards to the location of the image folder in actual site will be changed.

Is there a way to do this? Submodules seemed like a way to go at first but I don't think it helps with the problem I have.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just push a relative symbolic link if the path to the images directory is known  ?

Comment: symlink won't work. git will just save it as what it is--a symlink. When someone checkouts the branch he will just get a broken symlink.

Answer (score 1):

Create the image-folder and those images you want in it. Add them to git with git add. Then add your image folder to .gitignore.

git will continue to track your original files in the image folder but will not care for new files in there.

So if a user alter an already existing image, it will be noticed.

An other solution that I still think can be valid for you is git submodule.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a submodule for the image directory that you own and then maybe create a cronjob in your machine or the server(if you are running one) every 5 minutes or so to check if changes has been made to the image directory? If yes, then just pull the changes.